# Laravel5 won't match route edit_user/{id}

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

please, could you help me a bit?

I have this route in Laravel5:

```
Route::get('edit_user/{userId}', [
    'as' => 'editUser',
    'uses' => 'Auth\UserController@editUser'
]);
```

But when I try to go onto url `.../edit_user/19`  it wont match and redirect me into `/home` url...

Anyway, when I use this:

```
Route::get('edit_user/{userId}', [
    'as' => 'editUser',
    function($userId) {
        die($userId);
}
]);
```

It returns `19`.

Here is also my function:

```
public function editUser($userId) {
    die($userId);
}
```

Here is also part of my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


use App\Models\User;

use Auth;
use Hash;
use Mail;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }


    /**
     *
     * show edit user form
     *
     * @param $id
     */

    public function editUser($userId) {
        die($userId);
    }
```

Do you know any idea, where might be problem?

Thank you very much for your opinions.

**EDIT:**

I find out solution -> need to edit exception to auth in __construct.

Comment: Just as a side note: consider using RESTful routes. So it would be `/users/{userId}/edit`. Following such conventions will make your development experience much easier.

Comment: thank you. anyway -> if I changed this url, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Oh I just recommended that as a side note. I think whoacowboy is right about suspecting a middleware interference.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with the code provided.

Check the following items:

**1. Do you have this code in the `__construct` of your UsersController?**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

If so, you need to be lagged in to edit the user.

**2. Is there any route listed before `edit_user/{userId}` that would override this route.**

Try moving it to be the very first route.

**3. Is you UserController namespaced properly?**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
```

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm logged in -> to the edit user link I get from dropdown menu show only logged users. Part of controller I post into my question. You can see namespace is set well.